# Symfony 3.4 Overblog Graphql не могу понять как разобрать Query

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3, graphql

Всем привет, поставил https://github.com/overblog/GraphQLBundle на symgony 3.4 и сделал сдедующие типы

```
type RootQuery {
    post(limit: Int, offset: Int): [Post]
}

type Post {
        id: ID
        title(sort: String, search: String): String
        href: String
    }
```

далее я сделал ResolverMap

```
<?php

class PostMap extends ResolverMap
{

    /**
     * @return array|callable[]
     */
    public function map()
    {
        return [
            'RootQuery' => [
                self::RESOLVE_FIELD => function ($value, Argument $argument, \ArrayObject $context, ResolveInfo $info) {
                    $limit = $argument['limit'] ?? 10;
                    $offset = $argument['offset'] ?? 0;

                    $paginator = new Paginator((int)$limit, (int)$offset);

                    return $this->getData($paginator);
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Вроде все работает, но 1 момент понять не могу:

```
{
  post(limit:10) {
    id
    title(sort: "ASC")
    href
  }
}
```

"limit" я получить могу, но "sort" нет. Как я могу в ResolveMap это разобрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть в тип добавить `RootQuery`

```
type RootQuery {
    post(limit: Int, offset: Int, sort: String): [Post]
}
```

Ну и потом

```
$limit = $argument['limit'] ?? 10;
$offset = $argument['offset'] ?? 0;
$sort = $argument['sort'] ?? 'id';
```